# error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm new to android development. I am working on a small project and i have encountered a bug that i have been trying to solved it for almost a day.

So i have two Activity:

1. LoginpageActivity extends Activity
2. MainPageFragment extends FragmentActivity

In MainPageFragment i have 4 buttons on the top of the screen, and a fragment below those buttons. Those 4 buttons stay there all the time as long as I'm log in. whenever i press one of the 4 buttons. The fragment ui below those buttons will change.

The name of those buttons are : Home, Profile, Mode, exit

Now the problem is,  when i press Home button, the fragment page has two button: Offer and Request. When i press one of the two, it will jump to a page contains GOOGLE MAP.

If i press hardware BACK and try to go back to login page. The app will crash and say:

error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

But i don't have problem when i press BACK in other fragment page where there is no GOOGLE MAP.
I think it's GOOGLE MAP but i can't debug it.

Can anyone pls give me a hint? i'm really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using commitAllowingStateLoss(); instead of commmit when you push your fragment.

```
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me. I try you solution but it didn't work. my app still crash when i press hardware back when i'm in a fragment with google map